# Pointer variable reinitialized when encountered break statement

Tags: c++, pointers

```
    case 1: 
    {
        cout << "Enter two array size" << endl;

        cin >> num_arr_1; //size of array
        cin >> num_arr_2;

        int *parr_1 = new int[num_arr_1]; 
        int *parr_2 = new int[num_arr_2]; 
        //these two ptr variables had been initialized to NULL when declared

        for (int i = 0; i < num_arr_1; i++)
            cin >> *(parr_1 + i);

        for (int i = 0; i < num_arr_2; i++)
            cin >> *(parr_2 + i);       

        ifarray = 1;
        break; //where problems all begin!
    }
```

As the title says, i'm having a problem with pointer variables `parr_1` and `parr_2` being reinitialized to 0 when it encounters break statement.

Here the debugging steps:

- [before encountering the break statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ha50R.png)
- [just after the break statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2uaP.png)

I really dont know what's causing it to reinitialize...

As soon as i press F10("step over") it goes right into end of `switch` case and there isn't anything that might cause trouble between the break statement and end of the switch case.

Got any idea or experience with something like this??

btw i develop with visual studio using c++

Comment: You do you plan to use those after the `break` since they are declared in the local scope?

Comment: You have a memory leak at break. Why do you use local variables? Why do you use new instead of std::vector?

Comment: ㄴmanni66 

This is like first year in school and i dont know much about c++... thats something new for me! Thanks though

Comment: please click the accept answer for the answer that solved your problem. That is how this site works. I have removed "solved" from your title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are actually redeclaring the two variables in local scope (note int * parr_1 is declaration). You need to rewrite as:

```
     parr_1 = new int[num_arr_1]; 
     parr_2 = new int[num_arr_2];
```

Comment: oh wow i just realised damm... i was using same name for the variable as in main function. what a shame thanks!

Comment: Those lines had been in a different function i declared.
I made mistake while rewriting them

Comment: Excellent !  This was not obvious to spot within the code snippet !

Comment: @YunjaeGong Please click the accept button if you accept this answer and remove the "(solved)" in your title